# If a game uses the MVC pattern (on iOS), there are 3 classes: MVC, but why use an extra class ComputerPlayer?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am somewhat confused that, in a book, the design of the game on iOS is by using the MVC pattern. So we have

1. View, which is done by the Interface Builder, and drawing connections out for the controls' properties / values (as outlets), and event handlers (as actions)
2. Model, which stores the states of the game, such as time remaining, and current player's score (human player)
3. Controller, which runs after the View is loaded, to populate the Model's data to the view, set up the Timer for the game, handle the user's tapping on the screen, etc (event handlers), and implement the event handler for the Timer events.

So this makes sense, but there is a also a fourth class called `ComputerPlayer`, which is to handle the game's rules and mechanics, such as creating the words for the human player to guess, tell how many remaining words for the human player to guess, and provide for the next word for the human player to guess.  **(Update: this ComputerPlayer is 100% used by the Model class... the Model code instantiated the ComputerPlayer object and then make calls to it).**

I don't quite understand why in this MVC model, there is an extra class `ComputerPlayer`?  Why not make this part of the `Model` class, or even part of the `Controller` class?

(It sort of looks like helpers, if compared to Ruby on Rails's MVC pattern.  But helpers are mostly called by the View code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Fuhrmanator said, It seems that ComputerPlayer is a considered a part of Model layer. However, you can view it also as an Utility class.

In MVC, Utility Class is not part of any Layer and can be accessed by any Layer.

Answer (score 1):

The **C** in the MV**C** pattern often talks to different controllers. So its not 1 to 1 relationship. Adding a ComputerPlayerController is perfectly valid in a MVC pattern, and encourraged.

Comment: but this ComputerPlayer is 100% used by the Model class... the Model code instantiated the ComputerPlayer object and then make calls to it

Comment: Why is your model instantiating objects? For me models/dataobject is just that, data. For example GameSore { /*CurrentScore */} If you want to do some calculations etc do that within your controller.

Comment: it is not me... it is the original code in the book.  it is possible that game programming is different from the MVC in Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1):

[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is more of an architectural organization, and so each element (M,V,C) is usually a group (or layer) of classes.

Perhaps your book is oversimplfying things by only speaking of one class for each. I would see the `ComputerPlayer` as an element of the Model layer. As you can see from the Wikipedia page, there are many interpretations/implementations of MVC.